# Unable to connect to TFS from VS 2013 but can connect from VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a free version of Vs 2015 on my machine and I am able to connect to TFS from it.
But recently my IT team installed the licensed version of VS 2013 from which I am unable to connect to TFS. All the projects are developed in Vs2013 hence I need to connect to TFS from VS2013

I can connect to the TFS server via the web browser(both chrome and IE) and through VS2015.

The TFS version is 2013 (Version 12.0.21106.0)

**None of the below steps I did had solved the issue:**

- Cleared the TFS cache on my system.
- Disconnected TFS from VS2015,rebooted system and tried to connect from VS2013 but no success.
- Cleared my browser history

It throws the below error:
[image]

Comment: What update of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: I didnt follow your question @DaveShaw, What update? can you give me an example please

Comment: In Visual Studio, do Help, About what release is it on? VS2013 needs an update to talk to TFS2015 IIRC

Comment: I am using Visual studio 2013((Version 12.0.21005.1)) and the Tfs server is also TFS 2013 (Version 12.0.21106.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could fix this , the issue was the firewall was blocking the Port 443 via VS 2013 but was open for VS2015. I am not sure why it did that but when I added the port it worked.

Comment: @DaD, I have the same issue and I have added the inbound as well as an outbound rule for the same. But still, it gives the same error. Have done any other changes or configuration?

Answer (score 0):

If you could connect to VS2015 and fail with VS2013. This issue may related to your account cache.

Try to **remove** your office account info which stored in **Credential Manager** （*Control Panel-All Control Panel Items-Credential Manager-Windows Manager*）

[image]

Also [clear TFS and VS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/). Then reconnect  to TFS in Visual Studio 2013 and enter your account. If the issue still exists after above, you could give a try with reinstalling VS.

Comment: Thank you Patrick. Implemented the above steps but still not working.
Will have VS 2013 reinstalled today and see if that'll fix it.

Comment: I could fix this , the issue was the firewall was blocking the Port 443 via VS 2013 but was open for VS2015. 
I am not sure why it did that but when I added the port it worked.